# C++ - shuffle : required from here

Tags: c++, opencv, shuffle

I am pretty new to C++, however, I am trying to create some salt and pepper noise.
It is pretty much finished, only inbetween I want to shuffle an array of ints and no matter what I do and no matter what shuffle function I use, I always get that obnoxious "required from here" which does not tell me anything.
Here is my code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>



using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
 cv::Mat m( 256, 256, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(255) );

      //   Print it
      //  int counter = 0;



        unsigned int range = 255 - 0 + 1;
        int num = rand() % range ;



       int x[256];
       for (int i = 0; i<256; i++){
           x[i]= i;

       }


       srand(17);
       auto engine = std::default_random_engine{};
       shuffle(x[0], x[255], engine);
       int coord[256][256];
       for (int t= 0; t<256; t++){
           coord[t][t] = x[t];
       }

       for (int j = 0; j<256; j++){
           for (int k = 0; 0<256; k++)
           {if (coord[j][k]<=num){
               cv::Mat black( m, cv::Rect( j, k, 1, 1) );
               black = cv::Scalar( 0, 0, 0 );
           }

           }
       }

// Create a named window
             cv::namedWindow( "Test", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

             // Display
             imshow( "Test", m );

             // Wait until a key is pressed
             cv::waitKey(0);

              return 0;
        };
```

The mistake I get seems to be caused by this line:

```
shuffle(x[0], x[255], engine);
```

Now, I am happy to give the full compiler text but some of the lines are so long that it is impossible to do the necessary indents, I have tried.
Does anyone have a workaround for that?

Comment: For the future, please provide a [mcve], with emphasize on the *minimal*. The problem is completely unrelated to opencv and those loops etc.

Comment: Also `srand` will not seed your `std::default_random_engine`, which you seem to expect. Read the [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass iterator, not value.

It should be

```
shuffle(std::begin(x), std::end(x), engine);
```

or

```
shuffle(x, x + 256, engine);
```